# Centered div and a right to left picture

Tags: html, css

I want to put a picture right to left of my header div.
Failed to do it. Could you help me?

The Div is 80% width
and centered with "margin: 0 10%;"

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Yakir Freed </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Yakir Freed" />
    <div id="header">
    </div>
</head>
```

CSS Code :

```
body {
background-color: darkgray;
background-image: url('../images/website.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#logo {
position: fixed;
display: inline-block;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
margin: 0 10%;
z-index: 2;
}

#header {
position: fixed;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 10%;
top: 0px;
width: 80%;
height : 150px;
background: rgb(217, 47, 54);
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right aligned to the outside of the red box header?
Could do something like this and change the `left: -279px` to the width of your logo

```css
body {
  background-color: darkgray;
  background-image: url('../images/website.jpg');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: -279px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 80%;
  height : 150px;
  background: rgb(217, 47, 54);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title> Yakir Freed </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
          <img id="logo" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Yakir Freed" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry if I was uncleared.
I want the header div centered as it right now.
And the picture tight to outer left side of div #Header

Comment: So you just want the image left aligned inside of the red box? Maybe it's unclear because I can't see your logo image. Not sure if seeing that would help or not.

Comment: I repeat - outer left side

Comment: Updated with Google logo for example. Change the `left: -279px` to whatever the width of your logo is.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful & easy solution !